# Extracting a DOM element into an array of lines

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a page that includes a div with `contenteditable="true"` and I need to extract the text typed by the user as plain text to be later processed by some other javascript code. I then wrote this function:

```js
function extractLines(elem) {
    var nodes = elem.childNodes;
    var lines = [];
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
        var node = nodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            if (node.nodeValue.length > 0) {
                lines.push(node.nodeValue);
            }
        }
        if (node.nodeType == 1) {
            if (node.nodeName == "BR") {
                lines.push("");
            }
            else {
                lines = lines.concat(extractLines(node));
            }
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

This takes an element and should return an array of lines. I don't expect it to work for any HTML, but it should be able to process what the browser generates on the div. Currently I'm testing on Chrome only (later I'll expand the idea to other browsers as they format of generated html is different on contenteditable divs).

Given this HTML:

```html
<div id="target">aaa<div><br></div></div>
```

It correctly produces:

```js
["aaa", ""]
```

But my problem is when the user insert two consecutive line breaks (<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>). Chrome produces this:

```html
<div id="target">aaa<div><br></div><div><br></div></div>
```

And my code gets stuck into an infinite loop. Why?

You can try with this:

```js
console.log(extractLines(target));
```

Note: you might need to force-kill the tab (use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AgaLAle/6/edit)**

```
var myElem = document.getElementById('myElem');
var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

myBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var results = [];
  var children = myElem.childNodes;
  for (var i=0; i<children.length; ++i) {
    var child = children[i];
    if (child.nodeName === '#text') {
      results.push(child.textContent);   
    }
    else {
      var subChildren = child.childNodes;
      for (var j=0; j<subChildren.length; ++j) {
        var subChild = subChildren[j];
        results.push(subChild.textContent);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(results);
});
```

### Old Answer

How about this? **[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AgaLAle/3/edit)**

```
var myElem = document.getElementById('myElem');
var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

myBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var results = [];
  var children = myElem.childNodes;
  for (var i=0; i<children.length; ++i) {
    var text = children[i].textContent;
    if (text) { //remove empty lines
      results.push(text);
    }
  }
  console.log(results);
});
```

You can remove that `if (text)` statement if you want to keep the empty lines.

Comment: It omits some empty lines even without the if. Try writing two lines of text. Then go to the end of the first one and press Enter. The desired output would be `["aaa", "", "bbb"]`, but it gives `["aaa", "bbb"]`.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal jQuery would make short work of this....mind if I show you how to do it and then you can write out the logic without the use of jQuery? It's just a lot more code.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Nevermind about the jQuery, I think I solved it pretty easily without it. See my updated answer.

Comment: This seems much better. But another case where it fails: Write `abcd`, then break the line between `cd`, then between `bc`, then between `ab`. The output is `["a", "b", "cd"]` instead of `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`. But it is just a matter of making it recursive. Thank you!

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Not sure :( It's a little bit confusing. Not necessarily your code...but just trying to keep up with nodes in general.

Comment: I couldn't make the recursion work. It gets into an endless loop as well. I don't see what is wrong here. (the code is very similar to my original one. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xwCwbJTc)). Any ideas?